# Return value for Dart cascade

Tags: dart, cascade

I'm trying to use the Dart cascade operator to implement a builder pattern.

I have this (hacked) class:

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';
class Scope
{
   
   void value<T>(ScopeKey<T> key, T value) {}
   R run<R>(R Function() callback) => callback();
}

int use(String key) => 18;
```

I want to use a cascade to call the 'run' method which should return a value.

What I want to do is:

```dart
      final ageKey = ScopeKey<int>();
      final age = Scope()
       ..value<int>(ageKey, 18);
       .run<int>(() => use(ageKey));

      expect(age, equals(18));
```

Note the single '.' before 'run'.

What I have to do is:

```dart
   final ageKey = ScopeKey<int>();
      final scope = Scope()..value<int>(ageKey, 18);

      final age = scope.run<int>(() => use(ageKey));

      expect(age, equals(18));
```

My understanding is that .. discards the result of the `value` call and instead returns the `Scope` object.

So `Scope()..value()` should return a Scope.

As such I'm expecting the call

`Scope()..value().run() => 1`

to return 1 as the left hand operand to run should be the `Scope` object.

Instead it generates a compile error:

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
> Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be

This implies that .run is using the return value of `value`.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add parenthesis so that `.run` is called on your `Scope`.

```dart
final age = (Scope()..value<int>(ageKey, 18)).run<int>(() => use(ageKey));
```

---

With cascades you can currently do things like this:

```dart
class Collection<T> {
  List<T> items = [];
  @override
  String toString() => 'Items($items)';
}

void main() {
  final items = Collection<int>()
    ..items.add(1);
  print(items);
}
```

This only works because `.add` is called on `items` rather than `Collection`. The downside is if you wanted to call a method on `Collection` after the cascade call you have to wrap the expression in parenthesis.

Comment: so my mistake was i assuming that the '.run' would apply to the scope which I thought was logical as the .. is meant to cause items to discard its return value.   Or is this an issue of precedence?  i.e. does . have a higher precedence than .. so it binds to item rather than scope?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain if precedence is the reason for the behavior or not, but if you look at the part about cascades in the language spec (https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.10.pdf): 
"For example, C()..foo.bar = 2 allows us to obtain a reference to the object
o which is the result of evaluating C(), and at the same time use o to invoke the
getter foo and the setter bar= on the value returned by that getter." You can see it says `bar=` is called on `foo` rather than `C()`.

Comment: Also, the language tour (https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation) uses this feature in the example with the `querySelector`.